# Break in getline loop c++

Tags: c++, getline

I want to get several lines of input in strings into a vector (or an array). I collect the strings with getline() and when all lines have been collected I wish to break the while loop. I tried with "if (line.empty)" then break, but it does not work. What am I doing wrong?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector<string> lines;
    string line; 
    while (getline(cin >> ws, line))
    {
        if (!line.empty())
        {
            lines.push_back(line);
        }
        if (line.empty())
            break;
    }  
    cout << "Done";
 return 0;
}
```

Comment: Btw, you don't need to call `line.empty` twice per loop. You check if it's not empty. If that's false, then it must be empty. Change your second `if` in the loop to just an `else`. Probably won't fix your problem, but it should be pointed out. Also, ***never omit curly braces***. It's a bad habit that *will* bite you eventually if misused.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this, as you are trying string then length function works better. Code goes ...

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector<string> lines;
    string line; 
    while (getline(cin >> ws, line))
    {
      if (!line.length())
            break;
            lines.push_back(line);

    }  
    for(int i=0;i<lines.size();i++)cout<<lines[i]<<endl;
 return 0;
}
```

If you are having trouble while reading multiple inputs , use cin>>ws (whitespace ) at starting of loop.

Input

```
asds  as
dsaf asd 
asdasd dsa 
fadsa asd
fasd sad 
afdas asd
```

Output

```
asds  as
dsaf asd 
asdasd dsa 
fadsa asd
fasd sad 
afdas asd
```